# Retrieving currently logged in user SID in a multiple logged in users system

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm facing an issue where user X, which is a non-admin user, runs an elevated program, retrieves the wrong SID information while fetching and querying the token associated with the current process.

My main limitation here is that I must use `winXP` compatible code, so `WSTx` functions are out of the question.

Methods I've tried:

1. I  tried extracting the SID from the interactive desktop / main window station, but these yield odd results.
2. Expanded env variables: `%USERPROFILE%`
3. Used `GetUserName()`

The last 2 actually retrieved the elevated user.

my code:

```
HANDLE hTok = NULL;
            if (false == OpenProcessToken(/*hProcess*/GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_QUERY, &hTok))
            {
                LOG_ERROR(L"Failed obtaining process' token");
                return false;
            }

            // get user info size
            LPBYTE pBuf = nullptr;
            DWORD dwSize = 0;
            bool bSuccess = false;
            if (false == GetTokenInformation(hTok, TokenUser, NULL, 0, &dwSize))
            {
                if (ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER != GetLastError())
                {
                    LOG_ERROR(L"Failed getting token information");
                    return false;
                }
            }

            do
            {
                pBuf = (BYTE*)::LocalAlloc(LPTR, dwSize);
                if (nullptr == pBuf)
                {
                    LOG_ERROR(L"Failed allocating buffer for token information");
                    break;
                }

                WCHAR* pSid = nullptr;
                if (GetTokenInformation(
                    hTok,
                    TokenUser,
                    pBuf,
                    dwSize,
                    &dwSize))
                {
                    PTOKEN_USER pUserToken = reinterpret_cast<PTOKEN_USER>(pBuf);
                    if (false == ConvertSidToString(pUserToken->User.Sid, &pSid))
                    {
                        LOG_ERROR(L"Failed converting sid to string");
                        break;
                    }

                    bSuccess = true;
                    ::LocalFree(pSid);
                }
            } while (false);

            if (pBuf)
                ::LocalFree(pBuf);

            if (hTok && INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE != hTok)
                ::CloseHandle(hTok);

            return bSuccess;
```

Another idea I had in mind, is to open `explorer.exe`'s token, but I encountered another issue when 2 users are logged in, how can I differentiate between the running `explorer.exe`s instances now?

**Edit**: If i retrieve Active desktop's SID using GetUserObjectInformation with UOI_USER_SID, i get the Logon Session which is 20 in length, is it possible to somehow translate this logon session into user session?

Comment: The WTS functions have been around since Windows 2000, actually.  Try using `WTSQuerySessionInformation()` to query for `WTSUserName` and `WTSDomainName`, then pass those values to `LookupAccountName()` to get the SID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WTS functions have been around since Windows 2000.

I can think of a few approaches to your issue.  Your elevated process can either:

1. use `WTSQuerySessionInformation()` to query the current session for `WTSUserName`/`WTSDomainName`, or `WTSSessionInfo` (which also provides domain/user), then pass those values to `LookupAccountName()` to get that user's SID.
2. use `OpenDesktop()` to open the current desktop, then use
   `GetUserObjectInformation()` to query it for `UOI_USER_SID`.
3. create a separate service running in the LocalSystem account that uses `WTSQueryUserToken()` to get the current session's user token (your app could pass its current SessionID to the service so it knows which session to query), then use `GetTokenInformation()` to query for its `TokenLogonSid`, and pass the SID back to your app.

Comment: Thanks Remy for the quick response, a few comments regarding your answer:
1. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383838%28v=vs.85%29.aspx clearly states that minimum supported client version is Windows Vista

2. UOI_USER_SID provides the Logon Session which is a well known SID formatted as 20 chars SID, the one I'm trying to extract is 36 chars in length.

3. is like 1

Comment: In face, looks like since Microsoft neglected their winXP support, they have updated the minimum version support to Vista.

Comment: @igalk: Unfortunately, you cannot trust the minimum OS versions mentioned on MSDN. Whenever Microsoft drops support for a given OS, they usually go through all of the MSDN documentation and bump up the minimum versions on the API docs. So in most cases, MSDN **does not** say which OS version any given API was **introduced in**, only which OS version the API is still **supported in**, which is not the same thing.  It is really annoying.

Comment: Put another way, *no* API is supported in Windows XP.  If you're developing for Windows XP, you're using unsupported API functions by definition.

Comment: Unsupported, from Microsoft's perspective (ie, if you try to open a support case related to XP, they won't give you support for it), but not from XP's perspective.  Obviously, the desired API functions either exist or not in XP (which you can check for at runtime), but MSDN will not tell you that information one way or the other anymore.

Comment: Regarding (2), I'm thinking the desktop object owner is probably the logged-on user.  But I don't suppose there's any guarantee that this won't change in future versions, so for a robust solution you need to use (1) or (3).  (And yes, it would be nice if MS would leave the historical information in MSDN, though I don't really blame them for removing it.  Can you still obtain old versions of the SDK headers if you really need to look this stuff up?)